# Выход на всех устройствах

Tags: поддержка

Возможно ли разлогиниться на сайте таким образом, чтобы разлогинивание произошло на всех устройствах с которых был выполнен вход?

Прошу прощения за возможно наивный вопрос. Просто нигде не нашёл информации об этом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку «[выйти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/logout)» в меню, сайт перенаправляет меня на страницу вида:

[image: страница выхода]

На этой странице, среди прочего, предлагается отметить галочку «Выйти на всех устройствах». Я ее не тестировал, но предположу что она работает.